# Showing a Typo3 backend module as a list

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I have created a backend module in Typo3 and it is showing under Web module. I instead want to display my modules database records as a list same as showing in **web>list module.**

I have given a code into my modules index page.

```
t3lib_utility_Http::redirect(t3lib_BEfunc::getModuleUrl('web_list', array(), '', TRUE) . '&' . $query);
```

But it's showing a list of contents only from root. It's path is showing as

> Path:  New TYPO3 site [0].

Answer (score 0):

You can't "send" the display of your module in the list module.

You have to use `ExtJS` components to generate the display of your data **like** the module list.